# Is There a bug in CameraX CameraView because it doesn't work?

Tags: android, kotlin, camera, android-camerax

**I am developing an android app that lets users to record videos. I am using CameraX and CameraView as my options. The code used to work 2 weeks ago, but starting this week, CameraView has been displaying black screen only. Are there any solutions to this or am I doing something wrong?**

**1) build.gradle(app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.cameraxprototype4"
        minSdkVersion 28
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    def camerax_version = "1.0.0-beta06"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:$camerax_version"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:$camerax_version"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:$camerax_version"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha13"

}
```

**2) manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.cameraxprototype4">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**3) camera activity**

```
package com.example.cameraxprototype4

import android.Manifest
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Environment
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
import androidx.camera.core.VideoCapture
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import java.io.File

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val TAG = MainActivity::class.java.simpleName

    var isRecording: Boolean = false

    var CAMERA_PERMISSION = Manifest.permission.CAMERA
    var RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION = Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO

    var RC_PERMISSION = 101

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val recordFiles = ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(this, Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES)
        val storageDirectory = recordFiles[0]
        val videoRecordingFilePath = "${storageDirectory.absoluteFile}/${System.currentTimeMillis()}_video.mp4"

        preview.setOnClickListener {
            if (isRecording) {
                isRecording = false
                record.text = "Record Video"
                Toast.makeText(this, "Recording Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                preview.stopRecording()
            } else {
                isRecording = true
                record.text = "Stop Recording"
                Toast.makeText(this, "Recording Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                recordVideo(videoRecordingFilePath)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun startCameraSession() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            preview.bindToLifecycle(this)
        }
    }

    private fun recordVideo(videoRecordingFilePath: String) {
        preview.startRecording(File(videoRecordingFilePath), ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this), object: VideoCapture.OnVideoSavedCallback {
            override fun onVideoSaved(file: File) {
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Recording Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                Log.d(TAG, "onVideoSaved $videoRecordingFilePath")
            }

            override fun onError(videoCaptureError: Int, message: String, cause: Throwable?) {
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Recording Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                Log.e(TAG, "onError $videoCaptureError $message")
            }
        })
    }

    private fun requestPermissions() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(CAMERA_PERMISSION, RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION), RC_PERMISSION)
    }

    private fun checkPermissions(): Boolean {
        return ((ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, CAMERA_PERMISSION)) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, CAMERA_PERMISSION)) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        when(requestCode) {
            RC_PERMISSION -> {
                var allPermissionsGranted = false
                for (result in grantResults) {
                    if (result != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        allPermissionsGranted = false
                        break
                    } else {
                        allPermissionsGranted = true
                    }
                }
                if (allPermissionsGranted) startCameraSession() else permissionsNotGranted()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun permissionsNotGranted() {
        AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Permissions required")
            .setMessage("These permissions are required to use this app. Please allow Camera and Audio permissions first")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Grant") { dialog, which -> requestPermissions() }
            .show()
    }
}
```

**4) camera XML Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.camera.view.CameraView
        android:id="@+id/preview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:lensFacing="back"
        app:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:pinchToZoomEnabled="true"
        app:captureMode="video"
        app:flash="off"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/record"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Try in another emulator

Comment: Is this the exact code you're using? Because it doesn't seem like you're calling `startCameraSession()` from the `onCreate()` method, which means your `CameraView` isn't being bound to a lifecycle owner.

Comment: I have tried in another emulators and other devices and it provides the same result

Comment: This is a code copied off from the original version. I am calling `startCameraSession()` at `onRequestPermission(...)` function, which should occur before `onCreate()`. Also, I have tried calling `startCameraSession()`, but it still shows black

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onRequestPermissionsResult()` is not called before `onCreate()`, it it invoked after you explicitly request a permission from the user and they either grant the permission or not (via the permission dialog).

Once `onCreate()` is called, you have to explicitly check if all the permissions you need are granted, if they are, you then call `preview.bindToLifecycle(this)`, if 1 or more of the permissions isn't granted, you request them first, then once `onRequestPermissionsResult()` is invoked, once again you check if the permissions are granted, then react accordingly.

So the logic should look like this:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    // ...
    if (checkPermissions()) {
        preview.bindToLifecycle(this)
    } else {
        requestPermissions()
    }
}

override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
    // ...
    if (requestCode == RC_PERMISSION) {
        if (checkPermissions()) {
            preview.bindToLifecycle(this)
        } else {
            // Handle the scenario where the user doesn't grant all the required permissions
        }
    }
}
```

Also, in your manifest file, you're declaring 3 permissions (`WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, `CAMERA`, `RECORD_AUDIO`), but `requestPermissions()` is missing the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, and `checkPermissions()` only checks the `CAMERA` permission. Make sure you request and check all the permissions.

Comment: oh, I see my problem now. Thank you!